# Optimizing the Django-SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I've 3 models.

```
class ShipmentPPTLMapping(models.Model):
    pptl_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'pptls')

class ShipmentBagSealMapping(models.Model):
    bag_seal = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = 'open')
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'bags')



class Shipment(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

**I need to write a query which filters out the status of those bags`from ShipmentBagSealMapping` which are `closed`, provided the `pptl_id` `from ShipmentPPTLMapping`.**

I've a `pptl_id` at the start. With that I filters out all the shipments related to that, since `shipments_obj` is related to `ShipmentBagSealMapping` , so using `shipments_obj` is the only way I can filter out the closed bags.

```
shipment_pptl_mapping_obj_list = ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(pptl_id = pptl_id)
```

Then I loop around the `shipment_pptl_mapping_obj_list` to find the bags with status `closed`.

```
for shipment_pptl_mapping_obj in shipment_pptl_mapping_obj_list:
    closed_bags = shipment_pptl_mapping_obj.shipment_id.bags.filter(status = 'closed')
    #and then again another loop
    for bags in closed_bags:
        #something
```

How can I find do everything just in 1 query?

**Here's my final code**

```
shipment_pptl_mapping_obj_list = ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(pptl_id = pptl_id)  #--> extend this
for shipment_pptl_mapping_obj in shipment_pptl_mapping_obj_list:
    closed_bags = shipment_pptl_mapping_obj.shipment_id.bags.filter(status = 'closed')
    for bags in closed_bags:
        #do something
```

I want something like this

```
closed_bags = Some Query
for bags in closed_bags:
    #do_something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first correct your models, foreign key's field names should not contains `_id` in end. That will cause many problems and disappointments later

```
class ShipmentPPTLMapping(models.Model):
    pptl_id = models.IntegerField() # if you id is Integer of course
    shipment = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'pptls')

class ShipmentBagSealMapping(models.Model):
    bag_seal = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = 'open')
    shipment = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'bags')



class Shipment(models.Model):
    job_id = models.IntegerField(max_length = 255)
```

Second

```
closed_bags = Shipment.objects.filter(pptls__pptl_id__exact=pptl_id, status='closed')
```

This should solve your question

Comment: **Error** `Cannot resolve keyword 'pptls' into field. Choices are: bag_seal, id, shipment_id, status"}`                                  `

Comment: Also why FK's field names should not contains `_id` in end? what problem are you referring to?

Comment: Django add `_id` to each FK field. You can access the id by `object.name_id` or `object.name` to access object. Updated an answer. The problem is that another programmer should use `name_id_id`

Comment: @user1162512 `ShipmentBagSealMapping` => `Shipment`